# Updates in the server backend are not being published to the web client

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js, websocket, signalr

I am creating a backend service that writes new articles into a database and, upon completion, publishes changes to listening client in the frontend layer. My problem is that these BE updates are not triggering my subscribers in the frontend layer.

Directly testing the TaskHub (signalR backend asp.net hub) layer seems to be working, but the UI is not being updated. Relevant code for the various layers follows (I might be missing a thing or two - ask if something is amiss).

**The order of things :**

starting off with calling this on the client side:

```
 var taskHub = $.connection.taskHub;

 $.connection.hub.start();
```

Then i have this Knockout function to do the update :

```
self.AddQuickNews = function() {
        taskHub.server.AddAndUpdateQuickNews(self.newContent());  /just a string
    }
```

On ASP.NET backend i have the following method to handle this :

```
public void AddAndUpdateQuickNews(string newContent)
    {
        ArticleServices.AddQuickNews(newContent); //add a new record
        var quicknews = ArticleServices.GetQuickNews();  // get all records
        Clients.All.updateQuickNews(quicknews);  // pass back to clients

    }
```

Handling the result on the Client :

```
taskHub.client.UpdateQuickNews = function (quicknews) {
    quicknewsmodel.quicknews(quicknews);
    console.log("SignalR -> " + quicknews);
    //console.log("Fra UpdateMatches: " + matches);
}
```

**XHR call to test the backend**

```
self.AddQuickNews = function () {
        var url = 'api/MainPage/AddQuickNews';
        var params = "?content=" + self.newContent();
        $.ajax({
            url: url + params,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                taskHub.server.updateQuickNews(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                //alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Since the BE logic seems to be working, the problem is most probably just isolated to setting up publishers and subscribers.

Comment: Are other client methods working? Is the `AddAndUpdateQuickNews` method in a `Hub` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, its because when You declare the listener in your Client Side, you are using Upper Case in the first letter. This behavior is not allowed in `SignalR`. You must change your listener becomes :

```
taskHub.client.updateQuickNews = function (quicknews) {
    quicknewsmodel.quicknews(quicknews);
    console.log("SignalR -> " + quicknews);
    //console.log("Fra UpdateMatches: " + matches);
}
```

`taskHub.server.addAndUpdateQuickNews(self.newContent());  /just a string`

Hope this would help you

Comment: "Method name matching is case-insensitive. For example, `Clients.All.addContosoChatMessageToPage` on the server will execute `AddContosoChatMessageToPage`, `addContosoChatMessageToPage`, or `addcontosochatmessagetopage` on the client." Taken from the official documentation.

Comment: That's right infact, .. It's hard to find my own mistakes when looking at the wrong places :) There was one additional error though, which was critical.

Since this is asp.net context related, and i'm using the httpcontext, this is not available in the hubcontext directly.. Problem is that i swallowed the error/excetion and it just continued as nothing was wrong.. So to fix this, i had to use : IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal; var identity = principal.Identity; , and then pass the neccecary information to the dependent services that rely on the information :)